# Condition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, lambda

I have a data frame which contains values in the following format:

```
S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  
A   0   0   d   e   
A   b   0   0   0   
A   b   c   0   e   
A   b   c   d   0   
A   b   c   d   e
```

I just want the count of the values in a row only if they are continuously present. If only one value is present initially then the count is zero, but if two continuous values are present in a row then it's two:

```
S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  Count
A   0   0   d   e   zero
A   b   0   0   0   two
A   b   c   0   e   three
A   b   c   d   0   four
A   b   c   d   e   five
```

Comment: So you could phrase it, "number of members of groups of 2 or more adjacent nonzero items"? Wouldn't row 1 above be 'one' ? since 'd e' are adjacent?

Comment: That would also work for me.  But I wanted it that to be if only 1 value is there and after that 0, then the count should be 0

Comment: So it's number of members of two or more on the left starting at leftmost column?

Comment: Yes, we count the leftmost elements but if contians 0 then the count stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare `0` values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for equal (`0` means values are numbers, if strings use `'0'`), get cumulative sum by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) per rows and count `0` values by `sum`, last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {0:'no value', 1:'zero', 2:'two', 3:'three', 4:'four', 5:'five'}

df['Count'] = df.eq(0).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1).map(d)
print (df)
  S1 S2 S3 S4 S5  Count
0  A  0  0  d  e   zero
1  A  b  0  0  0    two
2  A  b  c  0  e  three
3  A  b  c  d  0   four
4  A  b  c  d  e   five
```

Comment: Its giving five for all

Comment: @AkshaySachdeva - Can you test `df['Count'] = df.eq(0).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1).map(d)` - first `'0'` changed to `0` ?